# How to remove duplicate xml node based on attribute value using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have below xml and needs to remove duplicate 'hid' node and clubbed its children under single 'hID' node
source xml:

```
<Crq>
    <dataRequests />
    <customData>
        <Root>
            <pID value="28499">
                <hID value="309524">
                    <bill ID="rFE52E42A" billIndicator ="1"/>
                </hID>
                <hID value="309524">
                    <bill ID="r38870BD6" billIndicator ="1"/>
                </hID>
            </pID>
        </Root>
    </customData>
</Crq>
```

Expected result:

```
<Crq>
    <dataRequests />
    <customData>
        <Root>
            <pID value="28499">
                <hID value="309524">
                    <bill ID="rFE52E42A" billIndicator ="1"/>
                    <bill ID="r38870BD6" billIndicator ="1"/>
                </hID>
            </pID>
        </Root>
    </customData>
</Crq>
```

Only 1 'hID' node should be there and all bill node should get clubbed as they all have same hID node.

Comment: This seems to be a *grouping* question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: i think this one requires 2 groups, for pID and hID